# How to download a pdf file using beautiful soup if the link directly opens the pdf?

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup

I have a list of links to the `pdf` files that I need to download.

One of the links:

```
'https://monentreprise.bj/documentCertificat/get?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6Ijg2Njk4MyJ9.xAXlH2CWvVMrs5hwk1rCcEIeKMRFmJAYetrgWJe6qE0'
```

How can the code be written to directly save the response of that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use beautiful soup. You can use the [request](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library.

```
import requests

URL = 'https://monentreprise.bj/documentCertificat/get?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6Ijg2Njk4MyJ9.xAXlH2CWvVMrs5hwk1rCcEIeKMRFmJAYetrgWJe6qE0'
r = requests.get(URL)  
with open('file_name.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```